# Config TinyMCE, TinyMCErte by a external config JSON-File

Tags: tinymce, modx, modx-revolution, tinymce-plugins

In MODX Revo, TinyMCErte I try to configure the PlugIn via the key tinymcerte.external_config. The config-File has to be valid JSON.
Here is my block, it is ignored. 
I want TinyMCE not to convert special characters like german umlaute (öäü) and of cource & should stay & and not `&amp;`

```
tinymce.init({
    forced_root_block : false,
    entity_encoding : "raw"
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. TinyMCE Rich Text Editor (Ver. 1.1.1) is reading the external config file.
2. the path could be e.g. ../assets/components/tinymcerte/ext-config.json, but it would be advisible to store it in a non web accesible place.
   Although this github-entry implies that it reads external config files vom core-path, assets-path and base-path I was not able to get it to work.
3. the content of the external config file has to be valid JSON:

`{
  "forced_root_block" : false,
  "entity_encoding" : "raw"
}`

4. The keys must be wrapped in "", in contrast to "native" TinyMCE settings (but not sure on this one...)

Answer (score 0):

I did not managed to get the external config file working. I tried an absolute link and a relative. The file did not load anyway.

I edited the file tinymcerte.js in 
assets\components\tinymcerte\js\mgr

after this in line 60
tinymce.init(this.cfg);

I put in my configuration before closing the }:

```
  tinymce.init({
      selector: "#ta",
      schema: 'html5',
      element_format : 'xhtml',
      forced_root_block : false,
      entity_encoding : 'raw'
    })
```

Nevertheless the next update of the extra will destroy this fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration is connected from the side of php. Therefore, the absolute and relative paths do not work.

Use this kinds of location:

```
"{base_path}/file.cfg"
"{core_path}/file.cfg"
"{assets_path}/file.cfg"
```